# pipeline echo to gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, pipe

To call `printf("Hello!");` in C from terminal I use

```
echo '#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("Hello!");
}' > foo.c
```

and then call `gcc foo.c` to make the output. Unfortunately, the pipelining

```
echo '#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("Hello!");
}' | gcc
```

fails complaining for no input file. Ultimately, I want to have a script where I can compile a C `command` from terminal with `./script [command]`. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask when you want to do this? I cannot see any use of it.

Comment: @klutt: if the C code is generated by some program, you might want to do that. But indeed, it is not worth the pain

Comment: @klutt In general, pipelines are a Good Thing.  In general, any program should accept input from stdin, unless it has some very good reason for not doing so.  Just because you can't think of a good use for it, doesn't mean that having the general-purpose capability is not a good idea.  (Now, with that said, I agree it's hard to think of a situation where you'd actually need to pipe C code into a C compiler.  I implemented the symbolic link trick -- as described in by answer -- many many years ago, just for fun, but I don't think I've ever actually used it.)

Comment: Probably not what the OP was looking for, but another good way to execute small scraps of C "on the fly", in shell scripts or the like, is if you happen to have a C *interpreter*.  For example, having such an interpreter, I can just type `ci -c 'printf("Hello!\n");'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but you have to specify the language using the `-x` option. Specify input file as stdin, language as C using `-xc` (*if you want it to be C++, use `-xc++`*). So in your case the command would be

```
echo '#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("Hello!");
}' | gcc -o output.o -xc -
```

You can read more about [Command Line Compiler Arguments](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html): see [*Invoking GCC*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) chapter.

---

There is also another way to do this without `echo`:

```
gcc -o output.o -xc - <<< '#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("Hello!");
}'
```

---

However, as @Basile says,  **it is not worth the effort to avoid dealing with C files**. [Check his answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48003461/7347631).

Answer (score 3):

I have done this in the past by doing things like

```
ln -s /dev/stdin stdin.c
```

Now `stdin.c` is a symlink to `/dev/stdin`, i.e. a magic file "containing" anything I type or pipe to it.  But the filename ends in `.c`, so any C compiler should treat it as a C file.  Things like

```
(echo '#include <stdio.h>'
 echo 'int main(void) { printf("Hello, world!\n"); }') |
    cc stdin.c
```

work just fine.

(Obviously this assumes you're using a Unix-like system with symbolic links and `/dev/stdin`.)

---

Addendum: Obviously this also assumes you're using a one-pass C compiler! I believe I first tried this trick with `/dev/tty` and an older, two-pass compiler (probably Ritchie's original, although I no longer remember for sure), and it "worked fine" there also, as long as you typed the identical input twice. :-)  (Seriously.  `main(){printf("Hello, world!\n");}^Dmain(){printf("Hello, world!\n");}`, with a control-D in the middle.)

Answer (score 3):

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999843/841108) answers are explaining how to make `gcc` read C code from *stdin*, but notice that in practice 
 **it is not worth the effort to avoid dealing with C files**.

<sup>(I am guessing you are using some POSIX operating system like Linux; if not, adapt my answer to your OS and compiler)</sup>

Emitting C code automatically is usual practice (and many academic programming languages are [compiling to C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065), and many builds are using generated C code, e.g. from [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)). But there is no much gain to use pipes and *stdin*, because a C compiler takes a lot of time (notably for [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), which you often want, e.g. by compiling with `gcc -O2`).

So my recommendation is to put the generated C code in a genuine file (perhaps some temporary one which should be removed later appropriately). That file could be on some [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) file system if disk performance is an issue (and in practice it never is for `gcc` compiled source code), and that file could be temporary (e.g. removed later) if you want it to.

Notice that the `gcc` program is generally using temporary files internally itself (e.g. for generated assembler files or object files). You'll see them if you add `-v` to your `gcc` compilation command, e.g. if you compile `foo.c` with `gcc -v foo.c -o fooprog`. So there is no practical reason to avoid a C source file (since `gcc` uses temporary *files* anyway!).

If you want to generate code on the fly in a running program, you could generate temporary C code then compile it as a temporary [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) (with [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)) then [dynamically load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) that plugin (e.g. using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) & [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dsym.3.html) on Linux); but you could also use [JIT compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries like [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) or [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), etc.... Of course this requires some support from your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (e.g. to grow your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)): in pure standard [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), the set of functions is fixed at build time since defined in the union of your [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (the set of `.c` files comprising your program), and you cannot generate code at runtime.

If you want to generate some C program in some [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script), better use temporary files, e.g. with `tempfile`, `mktemp` etc... (and use [`trap` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) on `EXIT` and on `TERM` signal to remove the temporary files when the script terminates).

If you generate some temporary C code in your [build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build), good [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) programs (e.g. [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [`ninja`](http://ninja-build.org/)) can be configured to remove these temporary C files (e.g. read about [intermediate files](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#index-intermediate-files) for `make`).

Look also into [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) programming languages like Common Lisp. For example [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) is compiling into machine code at every [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) interaction.

Comment: It's true that compiling C code from stdin is impractical, but in arguing so strenuously here against the possibility, I can't help noticing that you've argued pretty strongly against the notion of pipes at all!  My own reading of the Unix Philosophy (which is admittedly overzealous at times) holds that you should *always* be able to pipe things, that you should *never* have to resort to temporary files.  (Now, with that said, if a C compiler which "violates" the Unix philosophy were written by the same people who first established the philosophy, obviously I'm not going to complain too much.)

Answer (score 1):

without echo something to pipeline, you can do like this:

```
gcc -x c - <<eof
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("Hello!");
}
eof
```