# GCC Fails to Locate GLFW Header File

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, include, glfw

I'm attempting to setup my environment for Vulkan projects, and I'm running into issues with GLFW. I'm using VSCode and GCC on my system running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS and I've installed GLFW using `sudo apt install libglfw3 libglfw3-dev`. I manually checked the install location, which is in `/usr/include/GLFW`, which I can confirm is included in my GCC include path.

I'm using this basic program to test that it installed correctly:

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> // doesn't work with glfw3native.h either

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

However I get this error when attempting to compile:

```
g++ -pthread -o test main.cpp -lglfw -lGLU -lGL -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXinerama -lX11 -lrt -ldl
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm truly stumped. Here's what my GCC include path looks like:

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
# 0 "<stdin>"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
```

And here's where GLFW is located:

```
~$ locate glfw3.h
/usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h
```

If there's a blatantly obvious error with my configuration I'd love to know,

Comment: Running that returns `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 215555 Dec  8  2021 /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h`

Comment: Can't see the problem. What happens if you try a full path in your `#include` directive?

Comment: And what do you get on `ls -ld /usr/include/GLFW`?

Comment: @john That returns `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  5 18:14 /usr/include/GLFW`. And using the full path results in the same error. The problem is just that it can't find the GLFW file, even though it's installed in the correct place as far as I can tell.

Comment: @273k The first line of `main.cpp` is empty, just a formatting issue on my part, so technically `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` was on the second line.

Comment: It's very weird. Could you try `echo "#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>" | gcc -xc++` and `echo "#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>" | gcc -xc`.

Comment: Running both in the terminal returns `gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.` am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does `cat /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h` work?

Comment: IDK. It should work as it's answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999819/pipeline-echo-to-gcc. Perhaps gcc is not an executable, but a command alias? I missed dash `-` at the end. Try it

Comment: @Alan Yup, that just prints the contents of the file, so I don't think the contents are the issue

Comment: Maybe try running the compiler under strace to see what gcc is actually trying to do and why it fails

Comment: `echo "#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>" | gcc -xc++ -`

Comment: After running with strace I can't find anything which elaborates on the issue, just the same error saying it can't find GLFW. Maybe I should just build from source and include it in the project, rather than relying on whatever apt serves up to me.

Comment: @273k piping the include statement to gcc results in the same error, because gcc can't find the library in the first place.

Comment: To update this, when I copy `main.cpp` to my home folder it has no trouble including GLFW, however when I try to work on it from any other folder (Ex. `/home/{myusername}/Dev/vk_course/`) it can't include it. Still looking into why this is.

Comment: I found the cause, I had installed VSCode via Flatpak which for some reason was causing this error. I reinstalled using `sudo apt install code` and that fixed it.